# set checkbox as non editable in listview with custom adapter

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview with custom adapter. Each item in the listview has a imageview, textview and a checkbox.

My requirement is that, if the value of the textview in a particular item is "xyz", i have to set that checkbox as non-editable(the checkbox should always be checked and the user is not permitted to uncheck it).

I have tried, setting, `setClickable(false)` and `setEnabled(false)`, but both didn't work. Please have a look at the code below...

`

```
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup root) {
        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null)
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_favorite_list, null);

        view.setTag(teams.get(position).get("name"));


        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(teams.get(
                position).get("name"));

        String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
        Log.d(Const.TAG, "Name = "+name);


        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view;
                // do something here..
        });

        if (favoriteTeams.contains(teams.get(position).get("name")))
            checkBox.setChecked(true);
        else
            checkBox.setChecked(false);

                    //Need to set the checkBox to non-editable
        if(teams.get(position).get("name").equalsIgnoreCase("xyz"))
        {
            Log.d(Const.TAG, "Position = "+position);
            Log.d(Const.TAG, "Team = "+teams.get(position).get("name").toString());
            checkBox.setClickable(false);
            checkBox.setEnabled(false);
        }



        return view;
    }
}
```

`

Comment: I tried to set the entire view(listview item) as clickable and that worked. Now the checkbox cannot be clicked. But, when I scroll the listview, other items in the listview are also getting set with the same property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okie, so here is what i did..

```
` 
//if(teams.get(position).get("name").equalsIgnoreCase("xyz"))
            if(view.getTag().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("xyz"))
            {

                Log.d(Const.TAG, "View is Clickable = "+view.isClickable());    
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                checkBox.setClickable(false);
            }
            else
            {
                view.setClickable(false);
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                checkBox.setClickable(true);

            }
`
```

And to be frank, I am not sure, if this is the best approach, but it worked. If someone has a better approach, please do share.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need an onCheckedChangeListener?

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try 
`checkBox.setOnClickListener(null);`